# C Timer Callback

Tags: c, windows, unix, timer, posix

Interested in something similar to JavaScript setTimeout in C on both UNIX and Windows.

Basically, I want:

```
start_timer(&function_pointer, int time_in_secs)
```

or as close to that as I can get.

Also, something similar to setInterval would be nice (where it calls the callback every n seconds), but that can be implemented using setTimeout :)

Comment: I can't accept two answers, and I have seperate answers for Unix and Windows.  I could use SDL, but the answers here are fine.  I'll just accept the windows one because there is only one person who answered that part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906(VS.85).aspx) in Win32 with a [TimerProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644907(VS.85).aspx) as the call back.

```
/* calls TimerProc once every 60000 milliseconds */
SetTimer(NULL, 1, 60000, TimerProc);
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try the POSIX interval timers, timer_create and timer_settime, as it allows you to specify a call back function directly without using signals.  To get the timer to expire just once ( and not keep repeating ):

> [timer_settime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timer_settime):  The reload value of
>   the timer shall be set to the value
>   specified by the it_interval member of
>   value. When a timer is armed with a
>   non-zero it_interval, a periodic (or
>   repetitive) timer is specified.

Here is extensive documentation of using these timers with a nice example from the Linux Programmer's Manual on kernel.org:

[timer_create - create a POSIX per-process timer](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)

Answer (score 2):

For UNIX, `man setitimer`.

Answer (score 1):

Some information about alarm() and setitimer() can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Setting-an-Alarm.html).  Note that the upcall function is a signal handler, so it is subject to all of the limitations and restrictions associated with signal handlers as described in great detail [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html).

As noted in the first link, alarm() is POSIX-based, setitimer() is not (although it is more flexible).

Comment: The current POSIX spec says setitimer() and getitimer() are obsolescent and may be removed in a future edition.  The recommended replacements are timer_gettime() and timer_settime().

Comment: @Jonathan, you're right, it looks like the glibc doc is incorrect (or at least misleading) regarding setitimer()/getitimer() being non-POSIX interfaces. Is something newer than the 2004 version of 1003.1 available online? The best I could find was here: http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification/.

Comment: The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7
IEEE Std 1003.1™-2008 at http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm

Answer (score -1):

Try glib. If you need portable code, there's high probability that you cannot write anything more portable than them ;)

http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.20/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add